# vim errors on vim startup when run in fish shell

Tags: shell, vim, tmux, fish

Here's my error:

```
~> vim .tmux.conf 
Error detected while processing /Users/###/.spf13-vim-3/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim:
line   23:
E484: Can't open file /var/folders/c4/4nb5t7cs3wb17_g1w5030xc40000gn/T/vmIMCqB/0
Error detected while processing /Users/###/.spf13-vim-3/.vim/bundle/vim-preview/plugin/preview.vim:
line   94:
E484: Can't open file /var/folders/c4/4nb5t7cs3wb17_g1w5030xc40000gn/T/vmIMCqB/1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I've checked those lines in each file and they both call system('uname'), which I'm unfamiliar with. I thought this error might have something to do with TERM (which is xterm-256color outside tmux and screen-256color inside), but changing this in the .tmux.conf has no effect.

This happens with any file.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.1, vim 7.3, tmux 1.6 and am using the fish shell.

Comment: Do these `/var/…` folders exist? Why is your `.vim/` folder located in that `~/.spf13-vim-3` folder? Why would `uname` try to read the content of some random temporary folder?

Comment: Does running `uname` at the console generate a similar error?

Comment: Michael - uname prints "Darwin"

Comment: Romani - /var exists, and after reading about the system() function I see that it executes a shell command and prints it to a temp file, then reads it back out...http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system()

Comment: Romani - also, spf13 is a customized vim distro (https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is caused by the use of the fish shell as the default shell (set in my `.tmux.conf`).
To solve the problem, add this to the top of your `.vimrc` file:

```
set shell=/bin/sh
```

This post helped me sort things out:
[Debian Bug report logs - #609599 vim-runtime: Error detected while processing ruby.vim](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=609599).
Also thanks to commenters @MichaelSchuller and @romainl.

Comment: specifically - I added

set shell=/bin/sh

to the beginning of my .vimrc

Comment: Thank you. This happened to me. I tried fish, got this error, and then reverted back to bash and still got it. For me, it was happening with the vim-sensible plugin.

    Error detected while processing /Users/jth21/.dotfiles/link/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible/plugin/sensible.vim:
    line   75:
    E484: Can't open file /var/folders/gp/ybhqyzf50jndxdmfk5qlq6t40000gq/T/vr3ui14/0
    Press ENTER or type command to continue

Adding `shell=/bin/sh` resolved to `~/.vimrc` resolved the issue for me as well.

Comment: @JohnH Did you set bash back as your default shell with chsh -s /bin/bash?

Comment: @SteveMoss I don't believe I did (but I can't remember for certain). I checked my bash history, and all my chsh commands are changing to fish. I also checked my fish history and it has no chsh commands recorded.